# How to call my field validators in my save method in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a field that requires alphanumeric characters. I force this constraint using a validator. Something like this:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

validate_alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[validate_alphanumeric,]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.call_validators() or whatever
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, this works automatically in my admin site, and model forms. However, when I create objects from the shell, or lets say a manual API endpoint, then the validator is not enforced.

Is there a built-in function in django like the one in my comments that I can just call in my save method? Or do I have to manually validate my field again in the save method? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the [validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) documentation. Basically, if you call an object's `full_clean()` method, you'll run all validations on the object. You can run only the individual field validators by calling `self.clean_fields()`.

But in general, it's not good practice to add validation in the `save()` method. The reason is that in most Django apps, you'd create a form (a `ModelForm`) which would call the validation methods and be able to return something meaningful to the user when validation fails.

When the model's `save()` method is called it's too late to show something to the user, so you can only `raise` an exception at that point (and crash).

The normal procedure (which the admin forms use) is: validate the form by calling `form.is_valid()` (which calls `full_clean()` on the model), then if and only if the form is valid, save the model.

The shell is not the regular interaction method and should be used only very carefully as it bypasses the normal flow of the application.

Comment: This makes sense. However, lets say I create a custom function within the model called `validate()`, and call that in the over-ridden `save()` method. The `validate()` returns formatted errors as a dictionary with a key called `flag`. After getting the result in the `save()` method, we check if the `flag` is True. If its true, we raise a `ValidationError` using the data in the dictionary. Does this method have any obvious problems with it?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, I really won't be using any forms in my application. Its basically going to be one big API.

Comment: When I said "form" I meant Django `Form`. Even if you only create a REST API, you will still want to process requests that post data to create new objects or update existing objects. The best way to check validity of the data (and use all the goodness Django gives you to avoid SQL injection etc...) is to still instantiate a `Form` or `ModelForm` in your view, validate it and then save it.

Comment: Your approach might work, but it could also break stuff, because you're not using Django's built-in classes to do this. The admin views for example will not expect a ValidationError when saving the model and therefore just 'crash' if you raise a validation error. Only `Forms` know how to handle a validation error, namely, adding the error to their `errors` property.

Comment: Fair enough, doing it my way would be pretty naive.